# iPhone Text and Image Display

Tags: iphone

I am creating a ebook iPhone application and it consists of a bunch of pages.

My problem is some of the pages consists of images.

Is there a way to put the text and image in the same component.

What would be the best way to acheive this?

Thanks

Comment: you mean images in between Texts... Or both are separated... ?

Comment: What do you mean by component?

The simple answer is yes. But I'm not exactly clear about your question to begin with.

Comment: i mean images in between text.

Comment: I mean UITextField as a component - sorry if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed an image in a `UITextField`, nor the more appropriate `UITextView`.  Consider turning your text into HTML, and using a `UIWebView` to display it.  This would allow you to easily embed images into the text.