# Display Image in between texts in iOS

Tags: ios, image, label

Is it possible to show images with Text?
I am aware that UITextField or UITextView does not supports anything except string.

But I have been using [Attributed Label](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) Which supports almost all the similar functionalities like displaying the text on HTML. this can be easily achieved by converting the string to HTML and displaying it on UIWebview.BUT I **DONT** want to use `UIWebView`.

So the question is Is this possible to display Images in between Texts?

**EG:**  Displaying a custom smiley(image) between texts.

**P.S** I have already seen below mentioned questions

[iPhone Text and Image Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490054/iphone-text-and-image-display)

[is it possible to add images in between the text view in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498418/is-it-possible-to-add-images-in-between-the-text-view-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

Please set image into textField rightView

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
[textField setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
textField.rightView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"asdsad.png"]];
```

For center image you need to create Custom UITextField class than only will possible[image]

Here steps for that:-

1. In Xcode, Project->New File->User Interface->Empty View->Create(CustomUITextField)
2. In Empty View->Take UITextField into empty view.
3. In Xcode, Project->New File->Cocoa Touch->Next->select Subclass of UITextField->Give name (CustomTextField)->Next
4. 2 file will create .h and .m
5. .h look like that way

> ## import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>`

```
@interface CustomUITextField : UITextField{

}
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *centerImage;

@end
```

6. .m look like file that way

   #import "CustomUITextField.h"

   ```
   @implementation CustomUITextField

   - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
   {
       self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
       if (self) {
           // Initialization code
       }
       return self;
   }


   // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
   // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
   {
       [self superclass];
       // Drawing code
       UIImageView *circle;
       circle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 5, 20, 20)];
       circle.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
       [self addSubview:circle];

   }


   @end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but like I said I need the images between the texts and not at left or right side. and there can be many images in the text.. Already provided the example in my question

Comment: Please see my comments for center image in UITextField. i have edited the answer.!!

Comment: Dude.. You are not able to get my question.. I don't need the image in the center.. I want image along with text anywhere... Like in chat you  can insert smiley anywhere.. Similar is the case.. *Eg:Hi Whats up? (smiley).. Were you serious with what you said last day (smiley)*

Comment: Okk Friend Let me check if i get something than i'll post you

Answer (score 0):

There are two properties in UITextField that can be used to place images.

> **rightView**
>
> The overlay view displayed on the right side of the text field.
>   @property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *rightView
>
> **leftView**
>
> The overlay view displayed on the left side of the text field.
>   @property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *leftView

Reference: [Official Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/leftView)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but like I said I need the images between the texts and not at left or right side. and there can be many images in the text.. Already provided the example in my question

Comment: refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371053/position-of-rightview-uitextfield/18372012#18372012
You can change the position of rightView or leftView to suit your needs. It will require some work but I think it is possible.

Comment: Buddy I need many images in between texts.. not a single one and the text is multiline

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"];

// From image to data
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];

NSString *imageString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"imageString:%@",imageString);
```

This would help you..
Happy coding